# I can't unmount a "ghost" pendrive

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive, unmount

The other day I put a Kingston flash drive from a friend that I could not format.
unfortunately for me the flash drive in the system remained as a ghost and i get this message every time I want to format or eject any removable storage device.

[image: the message]

I do not know what to do, , The stick is not even connected and I get this message (yes, I have already restarted the computer more than once this week)

here is the cat /proc/mounts

```
 me@mycomputer:~$ cat /proc/mounts
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,relatime,size=4031376k,nr_inodes=1007844,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=808424k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f519570c-e0ee-4d6a-ae99-44306679925b / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,relatime,size=4k,mode=755 0 0
none /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0 0
none /run/user tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755 0 0
none /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sda1 /boot ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda7 /home ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
binfmt_misc /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
systemd /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,name=systemd 0 0
gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs fuse.gvfsd-fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000 0 0
/dev/sda3 /media/mitchell/0CAB620D6149A898 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

any ideas?
please :c

(thanks gh8 for the edit tips)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat /proc/mounts`

Comment: Run the following command AFTER unplugging the flash drive. (I say this only to be sure) `sudo rm -r /media/mitchell/KINGSTON`

Comment: A.B i don't have the pendrive, but i run the command and it's works!!! Thanks you!

Comment: Converted my comment into an answer. **;)**

Comment: is THE answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say that it works, I've converted my comment into an answer:

Run the following command AFTER unplugging the flash drive. (I say this only to be sure)

```
sudo rm -r /media/mitchell/KINGSTON
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case `system-udevd` had crashed (and was using 100% CPU). Killing that fixed it.